# PHP Operator failing

Tags: php, html, mysqli, operators

I am using this code to select and compare dates and information from 2 separate MySQLi tables. The code should produce the `"discount_amount"`IF the discount code entered is the same as the discount code in the database OR the discount code in the database is set to `"open"`. Yet even with the dates set and the code set to `"open"` I am only getting the `discount_amount` if I type `"open"` in to the `"$design_discount_code"` manually.

```
if($discount_code == $design_discount_code or $discount_code == 'open' && $date >= $discount_start_date && $date <= $discount_end_date){
    $design_price_total = $discount_amount;
    $discount = 'yes';
} else {
    $design_price_total = $original_price;
    $discount = 'no';
}
```

I have also attempted to change the PHP operator to `||` and `xor` with no better results. Any ideas as to why it is only returning 'yes' when I type `"open"` and not automatically as it should?

Comment: You should check the precedence of `and` and `or` in php. You seem to assume that `or` has higher precedence, which is incorrect.

Comment: So I should perform my 'and' checks on the dates before the check on the design discount codes?

Comment: You should use parentheses to structure your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to assume that `or` has higher precedence than `and`. This is incorrect. You should use parentheses to indicate that the `or` check is one of the `and` conditions. Like this:

```
if(($discount_code == $design_discount_code or $discount_code == 'open') and $date >= $discount_start_date and $date <= $discount_end_date)
```

Also note that mixing the English and/or with the symbolic &&/|| is not a great idea.

Comment: I have updated my code using your example but am still getting the same results, with your code however when I type "open" in to the variable "$design_discount_code" I am not receiving the discount "yes". Have messed around with it and tried taking out the dates section to see if that was the problem but then the code is returning "yes" constantly no matter what is entered or if the database has the value of "open".

Comment: Ah, would have helped if I had remembered to update the database to test its accuracy! Do-h! All working as it should and I appreciate the help! All the best !

Answer (score -1):

Check the priority of the `and` and `or`, maybe you can use parentheses `()` to specify which should be evaluated first.

```
if( ( $discount_code == $design_discount_code || $discount_code == 'open') && ( $date >= $discount_start_date && $date <= $discount_end_date) )
```

Comment: please consider to post this as a comment instead of an answer, or show an example what you meant

Comment: @swidmann user cannot comment as, he don't have sufficient reputation to do that.

Comment: @Monk Ren - An example would be appreciated if you could, thanks

Comment: @Monk Ren, please provide an example, how the code would look like with your solution

Comment: I mean the "or" low priority,   careful   priority,